# How to get all the second child node of all the multiple parent nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a movies graph database and the structure is like user->movies (watched) ->keywords -> movies and so on. Keywords and movies are chained in a loop but I only need 2 child nodes that are movie that is closely related to watched movies. How can I do this, I'm new to neo4j and I have no idea, how to write a cypher query to this. Can anyone please help me?

I tried writing the query but didn't get the desired output. this is the query that I have written.

```
MATCH (u:user{userId:'0c8b9291d7b94e1fa24564cef2aa5bfe'})-[:watched]->(m:movie)-[*]->()<-[*]-(m1:movie) RETURN  m.title, m1.title limit 50
```

[image]

input graph:

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWrHX.png):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWrHX.png)

Comment: Please give us sample data and tell us your desired result. Thanks.

Comment: I want to return the movies that are closest to watched movies and i pasted the input graph data in question

Comment: Thanks for showing your sample data. In your example result, the movie "American Pie Presents: The Book Of Love" will show how many movies related to it?  Please show us what the correct result would look like.

Comment: here in the input graph, each keyword (yellow) nodes have single movies connected but there are some movies that consist of common keywords (eg: grace's room movie was connected to two keywords) like that I want movies that have more keywords in common. For example, in the input graph, i only need the output that returns grace's room (--> print common_keywords>=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that from the graph provided you have a keyword for each movie but some movies have more than one keyword and you are expecting to return those movies which have more than 2 keywords. If this is the case your query must be
`MATCH (u:user{userId:'0c8b9291d7b94e1fa24564cef2aa5bfe'})-[:watched]->(m:movie)-[:has_keyword]->(k:Keyword) with m,count(k) as keyWordCount where keyWordCount >= 2 return m`.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, It is partially right and I modified it a little, and its working fine, `match (u:user{userId:'0c8b9291d7b94e1fa24564cef2aa5bfe'})-[:watched]->(m:movie)-[:has_keyword]->(k:keyword)<-[:has_keyword]-(m1:movie) with m1,count(k) as keyWordCount where keyWordCount >= 34 return m1.title, keyWordCount order by keyWordCount DESC`

But I have a small doubt, it's like whenever I write without `with` it's giving me more results. I know with clause is used for chained queries but not understand the use over here. Could You please explain?

Comment: @PavuluriViratChowdary the reason for carrying movie node in with is that for each movie node we have many keywords so we are aggregating the keywords using count(). When doing so we get the result as the number of keywords for each movie.  So without doing aggregation the result would be more since we have not grouped it. Let me know If I'm not clear.